# Calling class member from .h file

Tags: class

In `.ino` file I have a class defined (called `IPmonitoring`).Also, inside the same `.ino` file, I call a `.h` file ( which is located "above" class `IPmonotoring`).

When I try to call members of `IPmonitoring` inside .h file - I get an error, which usually I solve using `extern`, but seemingly it is not the same for classes.

What should be done ?

Guy

Comment: the class definition is then not included in the .h file. So normally you would define that class in another .h file and then let the first .h file include the second .h file with the class definition.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "call a `.h` file."  You mean `#include` it?

Comment: You should not have code in a .h file unless it's `inline` or a template class.

Comment: @timemage - yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-think your layout, and your usage of the .h file.

- You should never have code in a .h file unless it is either `inline` or part of a `template` class.

A .h file should only contain hints about where other things are. Those things should then be in .cpp or .ino files.

For example your IPmonitoring class would be *declared* in a .h file, and *defined* (or *implemented*) in a .cpp file (or .ino file if you prefer). Any place you want to use that class you `#include` the .h file. In one place you may choose to create an instance of that class. It is that instance that you then reference with `extern`.

In the Arduino world it is common to create a single instance of the class in the class's .cpp file and `extern` it in the .h file so everywhere that you include the .h file instantly has access to that single instance of the object.

This is how most libraries are written.

For example:

```cpp
// IPMonitoring.h

class IPMonitoring {
    public: 
        void doStuff();
};

extern IPMonitoring ipMon;
```

And:

```cpp
// IPMonitoring.cpp

#include <IPMonitoring.h>

IPMonitoring ipMon;

void IPMonitoring::doStuff() {
    // Do something
}
```

And finally:

```cpp
// mySketch.ino

#include <IPMonitoring.h>

void setup() {
    ipMon.doSomething();
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: class templates are instantiated to create classes; likewise for function templates and functions.  The involvement of a template doesn't affect things beyond being an *incentive* to inline, since the export keyword never really took off and then was later removed from the standard.

Comment: Majenko  -Thank you. It all started as `.ino` file with functions. During writing the code I gathered all function into class, since I wanted 3 instances of it. And the `.h` file  gathers all the function I used for my wifi and MQTT of other class I'm constantly using... well thing started to get messy :)